# Dynamic list from GetType?

Tags: c#, list, petapoco

```
 Type t = Type.GetType("classname");
```

I got 't' like as class classname. I need like this.

```
  List<t> list = db.Fetch<t>("select * from classname");
```

I get error:

> "t" could not be found.

How can i use this?

Comment: Since you're getting the type at run time, it can't be typed like that. Not sure of the provider you're using, but can you instead write `var list = db.Fetch<object>("select * from classname");`?

Comment: you are confusing and mixing **linq** and **EF**.

Comment: Generic types are types not object of type `Type`. Your `t` is an object which happens to be of type `Type` you can't create a generic with that.

Comment: @Rob I got error "Operation could destabilize the runtime."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Type t = Type.GetType("classname");

- Gives you type details at run-time

> `List<t> list = db.Fetch<t>("select * from classname");`

- Needs Type information at compile time, since generics are verified at compile time

that's the reason its not working

Your options, use:

1. `db.Fetch<dynamic>("select * from classname");`

which can be used to access all the properties of a given `Type T`, only point is if a property doesn't exist then with dynamic type its a runtime exception not compile time error

If further required, you may use reflection to fill and object of Type T at run-time and where each property can be verified and filled and List can be created at run-time

Comment: i used dynamic i got error : "Operation could destabilize the runtime."

Comment: Error or warning ? Since the Dynamic type can fill in anywhere and its verified only at run-time

Comment: Which framework are you using to fetch the data. db object belongs to which framework ?

Comment: .Net 4.5 and PetaPoco used for db access

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ `List<dynamic> list = db.Fetch<dynamic>("select * from classname");` should be correct... Try checking if there are db columns that break everything (instead if `*` put some column names)

Comment: @xanatos same error got 'Operation could destabilize the runtime'.

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ You have your program running in medium trust. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41735678/petapoco-operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime

Comment: @xanatos thanks for pointing out the security requirement of PetaPoco